# $f(z_n) = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that there are two sequences $x_n,y_n\in (0,1)$ both convergent to $0$ such that $f(x_n)\to 0$, $f(y_n)\to 1$. Prove that there is a sequence $z_n\in (0,1)$ convergent to $0$ such that $f(z_n)\to \frac{1}{2}$.

I know that for small enough $\varepsilon$, I can find such a subsequence with the aid of the intermidiate value theorem (I can explain more if needed), but how do I show that this is true for all $\varepsilon$? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$ you have $f(x_n) < 1/2$ and $f(y_n) > 1/2$, in which case the IVT gives you a $z_n$ between $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $f(z_n) = 1/2$. So not only can you make $f(z_n)$ converge to $1/2$, you can make it equal $1/2$ for all sufficiently large $n$ (and thus for all $n$ by taking an appropriate subsequence).

Comment: Is that because you let $\varepsilon = 1/2$? And how does that guarantee that $z_n$ converges to 0?

Comment: Yes, you can take $\epsilon = 1/2$ or any smaller value. Then note that $z_n$ is sandwiched between $x_n$ and $y_n$, and both of the latter converge to zero. To be more precise, $0 < \min(x_n, y_n) \leq z_n \leq \max(x_n, y_n) \leq x_n + y_n$.

Comment: Yes true, but the $z_n$ were found after some $N$ dependent on $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Now we take an arbitrary $\varepsilon$ to show $z_n$ converges? This where I get lost.

Comment: Yes, for $\epsilon = 1/2$, there is some $N$ such that  $f(x_n) < 1/2$ and $f(y_n) > 1/2$ for all $n \geq N$. The IVT gives us a sequence $z_n$ satisfying $f(z_n) = 1/2$ and $0 < z_n \leq x_n + y_n$ for all $n \geq N$ (see my previous comment). The RHS of the inequality converges to zero as $n \to \infty$, hence $z_n \to 0$. And clearly $f(z_n)$ converges to $1/2$, because it's **equal** to $1/2$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.